# HTML/VBA Auto-Email at a Specific Time

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to get my VBA/HTML to automatically send emails at a specific time, however as the time I have it set to test at comes and goes, nothing happens. When I go to activate it manually, the debugger highlights the time value and says "invalid outside procedure". I am new to VBA and was wondering if anyone could help?

```
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:31:00"), Procedure = "RangetoHTML"

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function












Sub AutoEmail()
' You need to use this module with the RangetoHTML subroutine.
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Only send the visible cells in the selection.
    Set rng = Sheets("emailtest").Range("A10:E39").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' Change this

    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
               vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = Range("C6").Value ' Change this to the email addresses you want to send to
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Date & " " & "Daily MCAPS Part Update" ' Add in a subject
        .HTMLBody = Range("C5").Value 
        
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the e-mail message.
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)` needs a parameter. So, it must be passed when it is called. But I do not  have the knowledge to be possible to directly send an object like parameter and you must make a kind of trick. The function parameter must be declared `As String` and the range address will be sent and the range will be built inside the function. Something like this:

```
Function RangetoHTML(rngAdd As String)
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = Range(rngAdd)

   'then use it like you need

End Function
```

And the function will be called in this way:

```
Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:31:00"), "'RangetoHTML """ & rng.address & "'"
```